# Can you have cell specific background colors in the table-plus macro on Confluence?

Tags: confluence

I am using this table-plus macro with [Confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence_%28software%29):

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Table-plus+macro

Can I have cell level formatting? I only see column level formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do this with the {table-plus} macro. However, you can do it in Confluence with a more advanced table formatting plugin as [described by Zac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630592/can-you-have-cell-specific-background-colors-in-the-table-plus-macro-on-confluenc/1801507#1801507).

Answer (score 5):

How to do this all depends on what [plugins](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Macros) you have obtained and enabled.  The built-in table cell syntax, while concise, has nowhere to put such customization.  You may want to look at Adaptavist's plugin for [Content Formatting Macros](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Content+Formatting+Macros), especially the [table macro](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/AtlassianConfluence/table+macro) -- you can throw bgcolor attributes on the cells with no problem.

Of course, after a point, it starts to look a lot like html, in which case you may just want to enable the [HTML plugin](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/HTML+Plugin) that ships with Confluence, but you should first be aware of the security implications of doing so; it may not be appropriate for your environment.

Answer (score 5):

You can apply a style to the table, table row or table cell using `{html}` or user defined macro.

Here are three macros for setting the background colour for a table cell, table row or the whole table.

## Table Cell Background Colour macro

```
    ## Macro Title: tblcellbg
    ## Macro Description: Set background colour for a single table cell
    ## Macro has a body: N
    ## Categories: Formatting
    ## Body Processing: No body
    ## Output Format: HTML
    ## Output: JavaScript. Sets table cell background color via CSS 
    ## Developed By: Underverse (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2093966/underverse)
    ## License: BY-NC-SA
    ## @param bgcolour:title=Background Color|type=string|required=true|desc=HTML colour or a HTML numeric #value
    ##
    ## Check for a blank first parameter
    ##

    #if ($parambgcolour && $parambgcolour.length() > 0)  ## If a parm name was used 
       #set ($bgcolor = $parambgcolour)                           ## then set the value locally
    #elseif ($param0 && $param0.length() > 0)                 ## if no parm name
       #set ($bgcolor = $param0)                                     ## then use the first value
    #else
       #set ($bgcolor = "#DDFADE")                                 ## no value so set a default
    #end

    #if ($bgcolor.contains('#'))                                     ## For HTML colours #etc 
    #set ($bgcolorclass = $bgcolor.replaceAll('#', 'A'))   ## Substritute any other char
    #else
    #set ($bgcolorclass = $bgcolor)                            ## or use the colourname itself
    #end

    <script type="text/javascript" class="$bgcolorclass$bgcolorclass">
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$(".$bgcolorclass$bgcolorclass").closest("td").css({"background-color": "$bgcolor"});
    });
    </script>
```

You can then use this macro in a wiki markup table, wiki macro table or into the wiki editor to set the background colour of the table cell.

```
    || Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |  {tblcellbg:lightgreen} Apple | {tblcellbg:#FFFF33} Banana |  Pear |
```

## Table Row Background Colour macro

```
    ## Macro Title: tblrowbg
    ## Macro Description: Set background colour for a table row
    ## Macro has a body: N
    ## Categories: Formatting
    ## Body Processing: No body
    ## Output Format: HTML
    ## Output: JavaScript. Sets table row background color via CSS 
    ## Developed By: Underverse (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2093966/underverse)
    ## License: BY-NC-SA
    ## @param bgcolour:title=Background Color|type=string|required=true|desc=HTML colour or a HTML numeric #value
    ##
    ##
    ## Check for a blank first parameter
    ##

    #if ($parambgcolour && $parambgcolour.length() > 0)  ## If a parm name was used 
       #set ($bgcolor = $parambgcolour)                           ## then set the value locally
    #elseif ($param0 && $param0.length() > 0)                 ## if no parm name
    #set ($bgcolor = $param0)                                     ## then use the first value
    #else
       #set ($bgcolor = "#DDFADE")                                 ## no value so set a default
    #end

    #if ($bgcolor.contains('#'))                                     ## For HTML colours #etc 
    #set ($bgcolorclass = $bgcolor.replaceAll('#', 'A'))   ## Substritute any other char
    #else
    #set ($bgcolorclass = $bgcolor)                            ## or use the colourname itself
    #end

    <script type="text/javascript" class="$bgcolorclass$bgcolorclass">
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$(".$bgcolorclass$bgcolorclass").closest("tr").css({"background-color": "$bgcolor"});
    });
    </script>
```

Put the macro in one of the cells in the row to be set.

```
    || Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |  {tblrowbg:lightblue} Apple | Banana |  Pear |
```

Use this macro with {tblcellbg} for finer control of cell colours.

```
    || Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |  {tblrowbg:lightblue} Apple | {tblcellbg:#FFFF33} Banana |  Pear |
```

## Table Background Colour macro

```
    ## Macro Title: tblbg
    ## Macro Description: Set background colour for a table
    ## Macro has a body: N
    ## Categories: Formatting
    ## Body Processing: No body
    ## Output Format: HTML
    ## Output: JavaScript. Sets table background color via CSS 
    ## Developed By: Underverse (http://stackoverflow.com/users/2093966/underverse)
    ## License: BY-NC-SA
    ## @param bgcolour:title=Background Color|type=string|required=true|desc=HTML colour or a HTML numeric #value
    ##
    ##
    ## Check for a blank first parameter
    ##

    #if ($parambgcolour && $parambgcolour.length() > 0)  ## If a parm name was used 
       #set ($bgcolor = $parambgcolour)                           ## then set the value locally
    #elseif ($param0 && $param0.length() > 0)                 ## if no parm name
       #set ($bgcolor = $param0)                                     ## then use the first value
    #else
       #set ($bgcolor = "#DDFADE")                                 ## no value so set a default
    #end

    #if ($bgcolor.contains('#'))                                     ## For HTML colours #etc 
    #set ($bgcolorclass = $bgcolor.replaceAll('#', 'A'))   ## Substritute any other char
    #else
    #set ($bgcolorclass = $bgcolor)                            ## or use the colourname itself
    #end

    <script type="text/javascript" class="$bgcolorclass$bgcolorclass">
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$(".$bgcolorclass$bgcolorclass").closest("table").css({"background-color": "$bgcolor"});
    });
    </script>
```

Put the macro in one of the cells in the table.

```
    || {tblbg:lightblue} Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |   Apple | Banana |  Pear |
```

Can be used with {tblrowbg} and {tblcellbg}.

## JavaScript

Alternatively, wrap the javascript which sets the cell/row/table background colour {html} and put it into the table as code.

### JS Table Cell BG Colour

```
    || Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |   Apple |{html}<SCRIPT class=AFFFF33AFFFF33 type=text/javascript>
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$(".AFFFF33AFFFF33").closest("td").css({"background-color": "#FFFF33"});
    });        </SCRIPT> {html} Banana  |  Pear |
```

### JS Table Row BG Color

```
    ||  Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |  {html}<SCRIPT class=lightbluelightblue type=text/javascript>
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$(".lightbluelightblue").closest("tr").css({"background-color": "lightblue"});
    });
    </SCRIPT>{html} Apple | Banana |  Pear |
```

### JS Table BG Color

```
    || {html}<SCRIPT class=pinkpink type=text/javascript>
    AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
        AJS.$(".pinkpink").closest("table").css({"background-color": "pink"});
    });
    </SCRIPT>{html} Heading 1|| Heading 2 || Heading 3 | 
    |   Apple | Banana |  Pear |
```